# Fancybox on load with cookie in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, cookies, fancybox

I'm trying to load a video on the home page in Fancybox. And have a cookie to not load it if you've been on the site in the last 30 days.

It's a Wordpress site so I changed all the "$" to "jQuery". I have all this script exactly as you see it as the last thing before closing the body tag at the bottom of the footer.php file. I get the error "jQuery.cookie is not a function". I'm not really a coder, so assume I don't know any basic scripting.

I think this should work, but it doesn't.

```
<!-- Start video popup cookie script -->
<script src='http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cookies.js/0.4.0/cookies.min.js'></script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery) {
jQuery(function() {
    if (jQuery.cookie('mycookie')==='true') {
        // it hasn't been thirty days yet
    } else {
    jQuery.fancybox(
        'http://www.youtube.com/embed/oWCN8HvsULg?rel=0&wmode=transparent&autoplay=1',
        {
            'autoDimensions'    : false,
            'width'             : 800,
            'height'            : 600,
            'transitionIn'      : 'none',
            'transitionOut'     : 'none'
        }
    );
}
});

// set cookie to expire in 30 days
jQuery.cookie('mycookie', 'true', { expires: 30});
});
</script>
<!--end Video popup -->
```

Thanks for your help.

Dan

Comment: Dummy question, are you loading jQuery library before cookies plugin?

Comment: BenjasHu,All the code above appears just above </body>. So yes? I'm pretty sure it is, but it is in the footer.php file of a Wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your cookie script is a jQuery plugin. Try `Cookies('mycookie', 'true', { expires: 30});` instead.

Comment: Clayton, here is a link to the script for jQuery Cookies ... http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cookies.js/0.4.0/cookies.min.js ... is this wrong? Thanks.
I did try your suggestion no difference.

Comment: You can use that script. You're just calling it wrong. It's not a jquery plugin so don't use jQuery.cookie

Comment: Ohhhh. Wow you are right. I didn't know it wasn't jQuery Cookies. Thanks. I'll look at the documentation for cookies.js.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I needed to add an id (#vidBtnDan) to the video link (not shown below), and change the name of the file jquery.cookies.js to jq.cookies.js, Wordpress will not use jquery.cookies.js for some reason. Also Wordpress will not work with $ in your code, so you need to change all "$" to "jQuery".

Here is the code ...

```
<!-- start video popup scripts --> 
<script src="wp-includes/js/jquery/jq.cookie.js"></script>

<a id="inline" href="#vidPop"> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/wp-includes/js/jquery/jq.cookie.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if(jQuery.cookie("modal") != 'true') {
                jQuery("#vidBtnDan").fancybox({padding:0, margin:0}).trigger('click');
        jQuery.cookie("modal", "true", { path: '/', expires: 30 });  
    }
});
</script> 
<!-- end video scripts -->
```